# Выгрузка файла на сервер POST способом

Tags: python, post, urllib

Привет!
Обработчик формы ожидает, что ему придет файл. Можно ли с помощью модуля `urllib` реализовать отправку файла и других необходимых параметров?

Comment: Опишите поподробней, какая задача и что вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 5):

> Библиотека **requests**

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://codevar.ru/post'
>>> files = {'report.xls': open('C:\\report.xls', 'rb')}

>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что лучше с этим справится [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.6/index.html). Вроде про это еще [poster](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/poster/0.4), но requests помощнее будет.

Comment: Тогда возникает вопрос, как работать с cookies с помощью requests.

    import requests
    import http.cookiejar
    URL = '...whatever...'
    jar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
    requests.post('http://site.ru/login.php', data=loginData, cookies=jar)
    r = requests.get(URL, cookies=jar)

Выдает ошибку

>AttributeError: 'CookieJar' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Спасибо большое за ссылку! Но у меня питон 2.6.6, который не знает такой модуль requests
Что делать тогда, если мне нужно реализовать следующее?
Итак, пользователь заходит по адресу на страницу с формой, один из элементов которой является type=file. С помощью этого элемента выбирает человек файл и нажимает на кнопку отправки его серверу, который его должен получить и хотя бы просто вывести на экран.
Размер файла максимум в пределе 15-20 КБайт
Файл обычный текстовый- "конфиг."
Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

[Http client to POST using multipart/form-data (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306-http-client-to-post-using-multipartform-data/).