# Пересылка файла

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, requests

Нужно на Pythone (3.5) написать клиент отправляющий файл (example.txt) на сервер (000webhost). И серверную часть на php принимающую этот файл и сохраняющую его в некоторую папку. Как это сделать?

Comment: В официальных документациях и в интернете очень много информации об этом на все случаи жизни. Что именно у вас не получилось при решении этой задачи?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Выгрузка файла на сервер POST способом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/86126/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос [OKhttp как принять картинку (file) на php сервере?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/442253/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Клиент](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests

with open('example.txt', 'rb') as file:
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/upload.php', files=dict(file=file))
    r.raise_for_status()
```

[Сервер](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

```php
<?php

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'some-dir/example.txt')) {
  print "<p>success";
} else {
  http_response_code(400);
}

?>
```

Чтобы попробовать:

```bsh
$ echo abc >example.txt     # создайте example.txt
$ mkdir some-dir            # создайте папку some-dir
$ php -S localhost:8000 &   # запустите сервер
$ python upload-client.py   # запустите клиент
$ kill %1                   # остановите сервер
```

Проверьте что успешно загрузился файл:

```bsh
$ diff -s example.txt some-dir/example.txt
```

- встроенный сервер (`php -S`) предназначен только для разработки и тестирования — не открывайте к нему доступ из интернета. Используйте настоящий веб-сервер типа Nginx. Используйте https (Let's Encrypt). How To [Install Linux, Nginx, MySQL, PHP (LEMP stack) in Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04)
- не доверяйте файлам и метаинформации о файлах, загруженных из интернета  — явно проверяйте MIME типы, генерируйте свои имена, папку с загруженными файлами вне корня web-сервера поместите, настройте ограничение на наибольший размер файла на сервере, подумайте об ограничении загрузки только для выбранных пользователей и/или captcha [What is the most secure method for uploading a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/256172/4279)

Answer (score 0):

На стороне python скачиваетe какую-то библиотеку для работы с сетью, вроде cURL, составляете multipart from data запрос на сервер, на сервере если он уже настроен, и Apache готов принимать Файлы, прилитит файл во временную папку /tmp, а в PHP опять же если Apache или другой веб сервер настроен, Вы в массиве $_FILES получите все нужные Файлы. Весь это процесс надо настраивать(это очень не сложно), и немного почитать. Вопрос крайне общий, и довольно странный. Я обрисовал все обстрактно но истинно.

Comment: Зачем curl, если есть requests и urllib?

Comment: Я написал «вроде cURL», в пайтоне я совсем не шурупаю. В пыхе же, Курл лучшая либа для работы с прикладным уровнем сети.

Comment: Ну, в общем нет :-) Те же requests ровно то же самое позволяют писать с количеством кода раз в 10-20 меньше ;-)

Comment: Буду знать, спасибо.